# Ruby get days, hours and minutes from variable value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm newer to Ruby and am having a pickle of a time trying to figure out how to take a value in a hash and convert it to days, hours and minutes. Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a future amount of time that gets added to `DateTime.now`. Unfortunately, however, the conversion of days, hours, and minutes appear to be in milliseconds; not what I'd expect.

**Code**

```
puts "date_hash #{date_hash}"
puts "days #{date_hash['days']} - #{date_hash['days'].days}"
puts "hours #{date_hash['hours']} : #{date_hash['hours'].hours}"
puts "minutes #{date_hash['minutes']} : #{date_hash['minutes'].minutes}"

# below will not work (yet) until above is correct
# future = date_hash['days'].days + date_hash['hours'].hours + date_hash['minutes'].minutes
# end_date = DateTime.now + future
```

**Output:**

```
date_hash {"days"=>27, "hours"=>1, "minutes"=>13}
days 27 - 2332800 # would expect 27.days
hours 1 : 3600    # would expect 1.hour
minutes 13 : 780  # would expect 13.minutes
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> days 27 - 2332800 # would expect 27.days
> hours 1 : 3600    # would expect 1.hour
> minutes 13 : 780  # would expect 13.minutes
> ```

2332800 IS 27.days. Internally, all durations are represented in seconds anyway (so you can do math on them). When you use duration in the interpolation, there's an implicit `.to_s` call to convert it to string. Check this out:

```
27.days # => 27 days
27.days.to_s # => "2332800"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails should get you the correct date.  Only thing that I see wrong is that you are trying access the hash with symbols (date_hash[:days]) instead of strings (date_hash['days']).  Also, it would help to know what is the output you get when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Ruby solution. There may be a better way using Rails' date-time methods.

```
require 'time'

def fast_forward(date_hash)
  Time.at(Time.now + 60 * 
    (60 * (24 * date_hash["days"] + date_hash["hours"]) + date_hash["minutes"]))
end

date_hash = {"days"=>27, "hours"=>1, "minutes"=>13}

Time.now
  #=> 2017-06-09 22:43:33 -0700 
new_time = fast_forward(date_hash)
  #=> 2017-07-06 23:56:35 -0700
```

The time object `new_time` can then be used with methods in the class [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html) to extract the information of interest (year, day of week, hours, minutes, etc.).

Time is stored internally as seconds since the epoch. I performed the following steps.

- used the class method [Time::now](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-c-now) to obtain an instance (of `Time`) that represents (but is not equal to) the number of seconds since the epoch;
- invoked the instance method [Time#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-2B), which converts the time object to seconds and adds that to its argument, also seconds, and returns seconds (since the epoch); and
- converted that sum back to a `Time` instance using the class method [Time::at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html).